# Red exclamation mark next to layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, layers, data-source

I had a raster layer in my map document that suddenly became invisible in the map even though it is still in my table of contents. There is now a red exclamation mark next to it in the table of contents though. Even when I re-add the layer from my catalog the layer is invisible and keeps that red exclamation mark. I can't find any explanation of this or how to fix it. What does it mean and what can I do about it?

Comment: It depends on raster format sometimes, e.g. old folder based grids won't show if there is long path with spaces to that folder.

Comment: If the source has been corrupted, you won't ever see it on the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red exclamation mark is known as a broken link, you can use the MXD Doctor that can recover entities from the broken file to a new map document or to an existing map document.

- You can refer to the link [(Using the MXD Doctor)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/get-started/administer/using-the-mxd-doctor-utility.htm) for a better understanding

You can also follow the below steps to get the layer working.

1. In the table of contents, right-click on the layer and go to the properties
2. Select the source tab and use the set data source option
3. Navigate to the appropriate data source
4. Select the data and click OK
   [image]
5. You can refer to the link [(Repair a broken link)](https://support.esri.com/en/Technical-Article/000003951) for a better understanding

You can also click the red exclamation mark for a shortcut to "Set Data Source"

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I suspected it was a source issue. But even when I follow your directions and those in the link the exclamation mark remains. When I reopen layer properties, it now shows the correct source, but the issue hasn't gone away. I've tried restarting the program but that didn't fix it. I'd share an image but I'm new to this and don't know how to do that either.

Comment: @mfigura, the above-mentioned workflow should have resolved your concern, you can try using the MXD doctor, and check if the map document is fixed for the broken links.
Kindly, have a look at this link for a better understanding https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/get-started/administer/using-the-mxd-doctor-utility.htm

Comment: Try to add your raster to a new empty mxd to check if the problem come from your original mxd or from the raster itself